# Remover o indicador das Tabs da ActionBar no Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Por `default` as tabs da ActionBar vem com o indicador a azul (quanto está seleccionado) e a minha pergunta é como faço para remover esse indicador azul.

Pretendo usar ícones nessas tabs, mas como está aparece o ícone e o indicador a azul, daí querer remover o indicador. Estou a usar o *style* Holo

Comment: Kiotto, esta usando qual tema? Pergunto isso porque para remover o indicador é preciso alterar o estilo do seu app.

Comment: Editei o tópico e escrevi la o tema que estou a usar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remover o indicator não é fácil.

O background do `Tab` do `ActionBar` é estilizado dessa forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Licença, omitida por espaço -->

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_holo" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/list_focused_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_holo" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_pressed_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />
</selector>
```

Como pode ver, há uma combinação para cada uma dos estados: `state_selected`, `state_focused` e `state_pressed`.

O responsável por colocar o indicador é o estado `selected`, logo é só remover os itens que definem esse estado.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/list_focused_holo" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_pressed_holo_dark" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
</selector>
```

Retirei esse `drawable` do código fonte do [Tema Holo do Android](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/tab_indicator_ab_holo.xml).

Para estilizar o tab por completo é fácil, basta incluir um elemento em seu tema, para redefinir o background do `Tab`.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_tab_indicator_ab_holo</item>
</style>
```

Agora basta criar um arquivo chamado `my_tab_indicator_ab_holo.xml` na pasta `/res/drawable`.

É necessário conseguir as imagens `9 patch` que são referenciadas no `drawable` e são elas: `list_focused_holo`, `list_pressed_holo_dark` e `tab_unselected_pressed_holo`, porque não é possível referenciar os `resources` internos da plataforma.

Para isso, recorri ao [código fonte do Android no Github](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base) para obter esses `drawables`, os links são os seguintes, as imagens estão ao lado:

> **Resolução HDPI**:
>
> [list_focused_holo.9.png](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/list_focused_holo.9.png) - [image: drawable-hdpi/list_focused_holo.9.png]
>
> [list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png) - [image: drawable-hdpi/list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png]
>
> [tab_unselected_pressed_holo.9.png](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/tab_unselected_pressed_holo.9.png) - [image: drawable-hdpi/tab_unselected_pressed_holo.9.png]
>
> **Resolução MDPI**:
>
> [list_focused_holo.9.png](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/list_focused_holo.9.png) - [image: drawable-mdpi/list_focused_holo.9.png]
>
> [list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png) - [image: drawable-mdpi/list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png]
>
> [tab_unselected_pressed_holo.9.png](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/tab_unselected_pressed_holo.9.png) - [image: drawable-mdpi/tab_unselected_pressed_holo.9.png]
>
> **Resolução XHDPI**:
>
> [list_focused_holo.9.png](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/list_focused_holo.9.png) - [image: drawable-xhdpi/list_focused_holo.9.png]
>
> [list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png) - [image: drawable-xhdpi/list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png]
>
> [tab_unselected_pressed_holo.9.png](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/tab_unselected_pressed_holo.9.png) - [image: drawable-xhdpi/tab_unselected_pressed_holo.9.png]
>
> **Resolução XXHDPI**:
>
> [list_focused_holo.9.png](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-xxhdpi/list_focused_holo.9.png) - [image: drawable-xxhdpi/list_focused_holo.9.png]
>
> [list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-xxhdpi/list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png) - [image: drawable-xxhdpi/list_pressed_holo_dark.9.png]
>
> [tab_unselected_pressed_holo.9.png](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-xxhdpi/tab_unselected_pressed_holo.9.png) - [image: drawable-xxhdpi/tab_unselected_pressed_holo.9.png]

Baixe essas imagens e coloque nas respectivas pastas: `/res/drawable-hdpi`, `/res/drawable-mdpi`, `/res/drawable-xhdpi` e `/res/drawable-xxhdpi`.

Infelizmente essa é a única forma que vejo de estilizar, sem perder o background original.

Comment: Não usei tudo, só usei até ao xml do style e meti tudo transparente nos drawables e funcionou :)

Comment: Há, se dessa forma atende tudo bem. Mas as vezes é legal manter os estilos originais porque fornecem feedback de toque, por exemplo o `state_pressed`.